# ¿como se pueden limitar las rutas disponibles según un atributo de un User en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, auth

Tengo el modelo User, el cual debe hacer Login. El modelo User tiene agregado el atributo de país, y dependiendo del país, deben estar disponibles solo algunas vistas.

User debe tener acceso a las View designadas para su pais, claro, las demás rutas no deben ser accesibles por URL.

Entonces la cosa es restringir las vistas solo para usuarios que haigan hecho Login, y segun el atributo pais pueden ingresar por URL a algunas vistas.

**¿Como se puede implementar eso?** Para usuarios autenticados se puede hacer algo como:

`Auth::$user->pais`

**¿pero como se pone en las vistas o rutas para restringirlas?**

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: crear un middleware para autenticar el pais en el **handle** con un if:     if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->pais=='Canada') {         return $next($request); } pero no me anda bien, no se como implementarlo en las rutas

Comment: Muéstranos como trataste de usarlo en las rutas

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te dijeron. Lo que tienes que haces es un middleware que implemente una estrategia para redireccionar a tus usuarios.

> Paso 1: crear un middleware.

```
// en tu consola escribe
php artisan make:middleware UserContry
```

> Paso 2: Escribe la estrategia (no voy a implementar el patrón de diseño pero tu si deberias).

```
<?php
// recuerda que los middlewares se crean en la carpeta app/Http/Middleware

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class UserContry
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $country)
    {
     // obviamente aquí tu vas a implementar la estrategia para refeccionar a donde más te convenga
        if(Auth::check && Auth::user()->pais == $country)
          return $next($request);
        return redirect($country);
    }
}
```

> Paso 4: Registrar el middleware en el kernel

```
<?php
// este archivo esta en App/Http/Middleware

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;


class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // si quieres que agregarlo a un grupo esta es la zona. Pero se agregaran a todas las rutas que esten dentro del grupo es decir, Si estan en web a todas las peticiones web se le aplicara el middleware.

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
           
        ],

        'api' => [
            

        ],
    ];

   // Este middleware yo lo aplicaria por ruta o agruparia las rutas para aplicarlo

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'user_contry' => App\Http\Middleware\UserContry::class,
       
    ];
}
```

Una vez que lo registraste lo aplicas en las rutas.

> Paso 5: Aplicar el middleware

```
Route::group(["middlere" =>['user_contry']], function($routes){
   $routes->get('{contry}/view-1', "EjemploController@view_1");
});
```